# How to create a regular expression to obtain a list of strings?

Tags: regex, bash

hello I am working with a file that looks as follows:

```
AliceBlue
AntiqueWhite
Aqua
Aquamarine
Azure
Beige
Bisque
Black
BlanchedAlmond
Blue
BlueViolet
Brown
```

I would like to obtain from this one another list with the following structure:

```
"AliceBlue","AntiqueWhite","Aqua",...,
```

I order to achieve this I tried:

```
awk -vORS=, '{ print $1 }' listColors.txt | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

And I got:

```
AliceBlue,AntiqueWhite,...,
```

I almost achieve what I wanted but I think that I need to build a regular expression to add the double quotes to all the words, I am not an expert on regular expressions, I would like to appreciate any suggestion to complete the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
awk -v ORS=, '{$1= "\"" $1 "\""} 1' file; echo

"AliceBlue","AntiqueWhite","Aqua","Aquamarine","Azure","Beige","Bisque","Black","BlanchedAlmond","Blue","BlueViolet","Brown",
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful.